# Make system pause after even - android

Tags: android, sleep

I have an SensorEvenListener method that calculates acceleration, and when it reaches a certain point (When device is shaken with a decent amount of force), it calls on a method. The problem i have is that sometimes when you shake the phone the method is called several times. Is there a way to have it pause the SensorEventListener so my method isnt called on several times in one second?

Answer (score 1):

After the method is called why don't you unregister the listener for X seconds? And then re-register it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you is to have a counter that increment and fire your method after the counter is for example at 3 or 4 "shakes", it would represent a more realistic shake event, right now I think you have just the "bump" detection.